# Find Google Account for project name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm able to identify the Google App Engine project name via the app engine URL: $project-name$.appspot.com

The project name also matches with a very old Jenkins task that we have in our organizational jenkins server (that no longer runs).

However, I'm unable to find that project-name in any of our google cloud accounts and I need to disable/delete that project.

How can I find the google account that owns that project, so that I can disable/delete it?

Comment: Talk to whoever pays the bill. They may be able to give you more information about the account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `projects.serviceAccounts.list` from the [Cloud IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/) which:

> Lists the [ServiceAccounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts#ServiceAccount) for a project

Try it in this link:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/list

On the right side of the page you will see a **Try this API**. In the name field, input your project name this way:

```
projects/my-project-name
```

And the output will be a json similar to this:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "projects/my-project-name/serviceAccounts/my-project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "projectId": "my-project-name",
      "uniqueId": "111111111111111111111",
      "email": "my-project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "displayName": "App Engine app default service account",
      "etag": "abcdefghi="
    },
        //// 
    {
      "name": "projects/my-project-name/serviceAccounts/some-account-name@my-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "projectId": "my-project-name",
      "uniqueId": "222222222222222222222",
      "email": "some-account-name@my-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "displayName": "some-account-name",
      "etag": "abcdefghi=",
      "oauth2ClientId": "333333333333333333333"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the project isn't in that account, though, right? It sounds like OP doesn't even know *which* account it's under. Reminds me of the famous bash.org quote, "<erno> hm. I've lost a machine.. literally _lost_. it responds to ping, it works completely, I just can't figure out where in my apartment it is."

Comment: exactly, the issue here is to find an account given a project-id. To find a project inside an account the search field with "all" selected, in the project modal works fine.

Comment: Can you open a support case so we can gather more information and better handle your inquiry? Please go to this link https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/